# Selecing the First Row second column Datagridview vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

Having a little problem, im trying to populate a label with the 2nd row, 2nd column of a datagridview. It sort of works, but it selects the 2nd row 2nd column from the bottom instead of the top, my sql says to order by date descending, i dont know if this is causing the problem.

```
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

        connect()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT date, product, monofilament, sc300swirl, midswirl, temperature, humidity, username FROM [sqlccmthicknesstest] ORDER BY date DESC "

        Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = table

        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

        disconnect()

        DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

        Label4.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value
```

Any help would be great,
Many Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Note: The `Rows` and `Cells` collections are zero-indexed, so you'll need `Rows(1)` and `Cells(1)`

Comment: can you post a sample of the table data and what's wrong with your returned value?